# Do you need some water or a drink? Use me, and I won't get it from the sink

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, lateral-thinking

> So I'm at best neutral, neither truly first nor last,
> To me, ties are fruitful, our destinies set and cast.
>
> A simple sketch, now that sounds fun,
> Now I will etch, maybe a gun.
>
> Dawn approaches, though it's at noon we'll meet,
> Our friend coaches, he'll help you while you cheat.
>
> For when I act, one will be sure to die,
> For odds are stacked, bullets will surely fly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Draw

So I'm at best neutral, neither truly first nor last, 
To me, ties are fruitful, our destinies set and cast.

> To draw means to finish a contest with an equal score - a tie. With this result, there is no winner or loser

A simple sketch, now that sounds fun, 
Now I will etch, maybe a gun.

> To draw also means to produce a picture

Dawn approaches, though it's at noon we'll meet, 
Our friend coaches, he'll help you while you cheat.

> High noon is usually the preferred time for a gun duel in Western movies.

For when I act, one will be sure to die, 
For odds are stacked, bullets will surely fly.

> To draw is the act of pulling a gun from its holster in order to shoot

Title

> To draw means to take or obtain liquid from a container or receptacle.

Hidden Hint

> The first letters of each line spell STANDOFF. A stand-off may result from a draw and would signal the beginning of drawing of guns. Also, as Bass mentions in the comments, it may be a reference to a [Mexican standoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_standoff) which involves the drawing of guns.

Comment: Good job, like always. There is another clue, can you find it?

Comment: The hidden hint might also refer to the [Hispanic variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_standoff) that results from too many people doing the thing.